# How to model waiting for the feedback

Tags: bpmn

[image: Screenshot]

I am working on the process diagram. In one of the tasks, an actor is asking for the feedback regarding the document from the legal team. Only once the feedback has been received, an actor can start the next task (Task 2 in the screenshot).

Initially, I have modeled this part of the process using the loop task (in the screenshot) but I don't think it's right thing to do, because an actor is requesting for the feedback only once, no more, as the task suggests, and then waits for the feedback.

Having said that, my question is: How can I indicate in the diagram, that an actor requests for the feedback only once, then waits for it and only once received, he progresses to the next task.

Answer (score 0):

The looping task is repeating itself.  So your diagram is saying that you request feedback over and over again (which might very soon upset the legal team).  A small improvement could be (add the loop to the waiting task, only if it is an active waiting where something is done repeatedly while waiting):

[image]

The thing is that waiting idle for something to happen is not really an activity.  A better approach would be to model the real process, and use the events to show the real flow:

[image]

Of course,  up to you not to show the second lane, if it is out of your scope.

Comment: Hello Christophe,
Thank you for your suggestion. 
I would like to follow the second approach, but the legal lane is out of my scope. Can you suggest how can I use the second approach without drawing the Legal lane? How this can be done correctly?

Comment: Sure! You just keep the items of the first lane and get rid of any arrow crossing the boundaries. The intermediate message event remaining in your single lane will catch any incoming message events and wait for such an event if necessary. There is no need to show the outgoing request: without the second pool, it's just a useless detail.

Comment: Thanks, like that? ![Example](https://i.postimg.cc/CL2RNyWL/Example.png).

Comment: @Szyms45 yes, exactly !